# MFP 8.0 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken return error with errorCode CHALLENGE_HANDLING_CANCELED

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have similar problem as in this thread [MobileFirst 8.0 Direct Update failing after downloading the updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589286/mobilefirst-8-0-direct-update-failing-after-downloading-the-updates)

The app is working fine if there is no direct update available. I have also performed the suggested items from the above thread. But the problem persist.

Once I accept the update, the application will reload, internally it will call WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken again, however this time it will return error with the error code "CHALLENGE_HANDLING_CANCELED"

Does anybody has any suggestions what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour during direct update as the contents of the app gets changed after the direct update and this invokes failure callback in `WLAuthorizationManager.ObtainAccessToken`API.

Soon after direct update, the application reloads. `WLAuthorizationManager.ObtainAccessToken`API makes a call and returns success if the connectivity between server and client is proper.